# No me Modifica el fondo del Datatable en la parte donde estan las palabras 'Buscar:', 'Mostrando' y 'Registros'

Tags: css, datatables

php de la tabla si id, la clase he incluso un estilo que es el background pero no modifica el background donde esta el texto de 'Buscar:', 'Mostrando' y 'Registros':

```
<div class="contenido-principal-tabla" style="background-color: 303f9f !important;">
   <table id="table" class="display" style="background-color: 303f9f !important;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="centrado" scope="col">RUT</th>
          <th id="centrado" scope="col">Nombre</th>
          <th id="centrado" scope="col">Apellido</th>
          <th id="centrado" scope="col">Correo</th>
          <th id="centrado" scope="col">Rol</th>
          <th id="centrado" scope="col">Estado</th>
          <th id="centrado" scope="col">Modificar</th>
          <th id="centrado" scope="col">Permisos</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
```

css de la tabla:
en este css esta el diseño de la parte del buscador y del recuadro del selecto donde estan los rango de datos y a su vez tambien esta el estilo del contenedor de la tabla pero al igual que en el php no modifica el fonde de lo que vendria a ser el texto 'Buscar:', 'Mostrando' y 'Registros'.

```
.contenido-principal-tabla {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: justify;
  color: var(--text-box);
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 90%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.display{
  background-color: var(--main-color) !important;
}
.dataTables_length {
  background-color: var(--main-color) !important;
  border-color: var(--modal-border) !important;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length select {
  background-color: var(--main-color) !important;
  border-color: var(--modal-border) !important;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length select {
  background-color: var(--main-color) !important;
  border-color: var(--modal-border) !important;
}

/* dataTables Search input box */
.dataTables_filter {
  background-color: var(--main-color) !important;
  border-color: var(--modal-border) !important;
}
.dataTables_filter input {
  background-color: var(--main-color) !important;
  border-color: var(--modal-border) !important;
}
table.dataTable thead th,
table.dataTable thead td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--modal-border) !important;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover {
  color: var(--text-box) !important;
  border: 1px solid var(--modal-border)!important;
  background-color: var(--main-color)!important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, var(--main-color)), color-stop(100%, var(--main-color)))!important;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, var(--main-color) 0%, var(--main-color) 100%)!important;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, var(--main-color) 0%, var(--main-color) 100%)!important;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, var(--main-color) 0%, var(--main-color) 100%)!important;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, var(--main-color) 0%, var(--main-color) 100%)!important;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--main-color) 0%, var(--main-color) 100%)!important;
}
```

Comment: Pues a simple vista no logro ver de que parte del código hablas cuando dices ***el texto  'Buscar:', 'Mostrando' y 'Registros'***, por favor pulsa editar y agrega un poco más de detalle acerca de tu pregunta. ;)